# Cannot rename column neither exclude column in snowflake sql select query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Below query is working great

**Example 1**

```
SELECT
* EXCLUDE company_name
FROM employee
```

**Example 2**

```
SELECT 
* RENAME id as emp_id
FROM employee
```

But when I am trying to select with table alias name then it is not working and getting SQL error, I want to use alias for some joins and I am having ambiguous column error on column company_name

**Example 1**

```
SELECT
* EXCLUDE t1.company_name 
FROM employee t1
```

**Example 2**

```
SELECT 
* RENAME t1.id as emp_id
FROM employee t1
```

I followed the [Snowflake Docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/select) but not found anything related

> **SQL COMPILATION ERROR:** syntax error at line 1 at position 18 unexpected '.'.

Comment: Please update your question with the error that you’re getting

Comment: HI , the error "ambiguous column error on column" means a column with the same name is present in more than one table, you need to add an alias or table name to the column, please show the SQL that is being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/select#label-select-cmd-syntax-selected-columns:%7E:text=If%20you%20are%20selecting%20from%20multiple%20tables%2C%20use%20SELECT%20table_name.*%20to%20specify%20that%20you%20want%20to%20select%20all%20columns%20from%20a%20specific%20table%2C%20and%20specify%20the%20unqualified%20column%20name%20in%20EXCLUDE.%20For%20example%3A) says you cannot use qualified column names in either `exclude` or `rename`.

> If you are selecting from multiple tables, use SELECT table_name.* to
> specify that you want to select all columns from a specific table, and
> specify the unqualified column name in EXCLUDE. For example:
>
> SELECT table_a.* EXCLUDE column_in_table_a ,   table_b.* EXCLUDE
> column_in_table_b   ...

So change what you have to something like this

```
SELECT t1.* EXCLUDE company_name, t2.* EXCLUDE employee_id
FROM employee t1
JOIN salary t2 on t1.employee_id = t2.employee_id
```

Comment: thanks I have tried but still getting compilation error.

select t1.*, rename t1.company_name as c_name, t2.* from employee t1 inner join salary t2 on c_name = t2.company_name

Comment: @SayedMohdAli Change `rename t1.company_name` to just `rename company_name`